# Unilateral signal using DFT

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

I made a code for calculating DFT of any signal. I tested it with many functions but when I introduced a complex sine, my DFT give a "unilateral signal". I've never seen something like that. Is it OK? I supposed to get a bilateral DFT ($-f$ and $+f$).

Complex sine:
$$\exp(i\cdot2\cdot\pi\cdot2.5/128\cdot t)$$

My DFT plot:
[image: My DFT]

Is it OK? What does it mean?

Comment: What do you mean by a unilateral signal? The dft of a sequence of $n$ complex numbers is itself a sequence of $n$ complex numbers. Perhaps you are getting confused due to the natural inclusion from the reals into the complex a,la the isomorphism $r (\in \mathbb R) \mapsto r (\in \mathbb C)$

Comment: I don't understand what the -f and +f is referring to, except I tried to interpret it as meaning "dimension 2" aka complex?